# JSF Primefaces and Spring security User Managment ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I want to make simple user management. I have primefaces DataTables, when user is "ROLE_USER" I want to my DataTables not to be editable. But where user is ROLE_ADMIN I want my datatable to be editable.

I have properties in my ManagedBean

```
public boolean isAdmin;
```

When isAdmin is true I want datatable to be editable, if this is false then not editable.

I have solution but not working

```
<p:dataTable id="transactionTbl" var="tr"
value="#{reportParamManagedBean.reportsList}" rowKey="#{tr.id}"
editable="#{reportParamManagedBean.isAdmin}">
```

I have there error

Property 'isAdmin' not found on type MyBean

Please help, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add getter (and setter) in your bean:

```
private boolean isAdmin;

public boolean isAdmin() {
 return this.isAdmin;
}

public void setAdmin(boolean value) {
 this.isAdmin = value;
}
```

You probably have to retrieve the value as:

```
#{reportParamManagedBean.admin}
```